# In which cases should I prefer ES6-maps instead of JavaScript-objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently learning the new language-features which come into JavaScript with ES6.

JavaScript-objects have always be what I know from other languages as hash-maps or associative arrays.

Now the language has maps. But I ask myself: Are there really cases where it wouldn't be possible to accomplish the same thing by using an object as data-structure?

Okay ..., maps have a few comfortable methods extra. Nevertheless: I haven't been able to figure out a use-case in which the same couldn't be done by using an object.

Does anyone know why maps have become incorporated into the language?
Or better: Can anyone show me a use-case in which I would be better off using a map instead of an object?

Comment: Sure - when keys are not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are fine when you're using only using strings as your keys. But Maps will let you use other data types as your keys. Also, when you iterate over their keys and values, they have a predictable order (the order in which you inserted the elements).

[Have a look at the MDN here for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared)

Comment: Short & sweet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As often its all about a cleaner data-structure and to make things easier.

Here is a comparison what you can do with Map vs what you can do with an normal object

ECMAScript 6

```
let s = new Set()
s.add("hello").add("goodbye")

let m = new Map()
m.set("hello", 42)
m.set(s, 34)
m.get(s) === 34
m.size === 2
for (let [ key, val ] of m.entries())
    console.log(key + " = " + val)
```

ECMAScript 5

```
var s = {}; 
s["hello"] = true; s["goodbye"] = true;

var m = {};
m["hello"] = 42; 
// no equivalent in ES5 
// no equivalent in ES5
Object.keys(m).length === 2;
for (key in m) {
    if (m.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = m[key];
        console.log(key + " = " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Der Tieran : In the ECMAScript 6 example s is a variable? Declared somewhere above? The code-snippet by itself wouldn't work.

Comment: Also, looping through an object can be done more gracefully in ES5: `Object.keys(m).forEach(…);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an object as a map, then the keys can conflict with the built-in properties of objects. This can be a problem when the keys are read from the user or some external source.

```
var a = {};

// Put value in map
a['hasOwnProperty'] = 1;

for(x in a) {
    // TypeError: a.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```